# Is it possible to run UFT scripts on virtual machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, hp-uft

I am writing scripts which will install UFT and do all the configuration setting require to run the UFT scripts. My UFT scripts are browsing some urls etc.

I want to know if I do it in Virutal Machines then is it possible to run the UFT scripts on those servers as they won't have mouse and keyboards attached.

Want to run automatically on machines without logging into the machines.

Answer (score 3):

In case if you are simulating mouse & keyboard actions (like hitting ENTER, Clicking on particular coordinate etc) in your script, It will work fine even if mouse and keyboards are not connected to a computer. Basically you are simulating mouse and keyboard clicks w/o actually using them.I assume you have verified your scripts in your local machine. If it works fine, Then it will also work fine in your VM.(assuming your VM has enough permissions/all the prerequisites installed/configured etc).

Answer (score 0):

It works.  I use it every day.  You can even use analog recording in the VM with a Remote Connection to the VM with no problems as well.